# Execute DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS with Smo?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, smo, dbcc

Is there an Smo method that executes TSQLs `DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS` on a database and returns  the occuring messages as `IEnumerable<String>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like, if you have a look at the SMO programming guide for the database class, there isn't anything listed for check constraints:

[MSDN - SMO Reference Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.aspx)